# How to use Yii2 code generator using kartik widgets

Tags: yii2, code-generation, kartik-v

How can I configure Yii2 code generator to use kartik widgets (or any other custom widgets) by default?

Comment: you can use this [extencion](https://github.com/johnitvn/yii2-ajaxcrud)
edit it or check how it's made and make your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the template for the corresponding model. See here: https://github.com/schmunk42/yii2-giiant/blob/master/docs/30-using-providers.md